# Excel spreadsheet delete all the shaded values

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have an excel spreadsheet that has shaded and no shaded fields. I am new to Excel so I really do not know how to do the following:

I want to delete the values of all the shaded cells. Basically I want to highlight all of the cells then change the formula (below) so that all the shaded field values get deleted.

When I click on a shaded cell, I have this formula:
=IF(SUM('ELEC MEP'!C2,-'ELEC AXIS'!E2)=0,'ELEC MEP'!C2,'ELEC AXIS'!E2)

When I click on a non shaded cell, I have this formula:
=IF(SUM('ELEC MEP'!G4,-'ELEC AXIS'!I4)=0,'ELEC MEP'!G4,'ELEC AXIS'!I4)

When I highlight both shaded and non shaded cells:
=IF(SUM('ELEC MEP'!H4,-'ELEC AXIS'!J4)=0,'ELEC MEP'!H4,'ELEC AXIS'!J4)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though simply adding a filter to the Row Header would fix this issue. Simply add the filter, select the "Filter By Color" option, filter by the color in question, and then highlight and delete cells, or manually change their color to "No Shade/Fill".